# I cannot load my "rgl" library correctly. why?

Tags: r, macos, rgl

I have this problem while loading my rgl library in R 0.99.491 & Mac OS X 10_11_3.

```
  > library(rgl)
 Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
 call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 error: unable to load shared object'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl   .so':
 dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl    .so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
 Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
 Reason: image not found
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’
```

the installation is ok. but loading is not done. 
the Xcode is also installed. can you please help me solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: your R is quite old! the current version is 3.2.3!!

Comment: @MLavoie  This the version of RStudio. OP is mixing R and RStudio. Look at the error message, it is R 3.2.x.

Comment: thanks @Pascal :-) OP could your provide the sessionInfo()

Comment: Actually I made a mistake and gave my Rstudio version. my R version is   3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree". Sorry.

Comment: and here is the sessioninfo(): `> sessionInfo()`
`R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)`
`Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)`
`Running under: OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)`

`locale:`
`[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8`

`attached base packages:`
`[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base  `   

`loaded via a namespace (and not attached):`
`[1] colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.3.0     plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.2.3   `   `gtable_0.1.2     Rcpp_0.12.3      ggplot2_2.0.0   `
`[8] grid_3.2.3       munsell_0.4.2  `

Comment: @Pascal : don't you know the solution?

Comment: @MLavoie : don't you know the solution?

Comment: No, I don't know. Not a OSX user.

Comment: maybe this thread will help you https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2015-October/011680.html